# Regex to ignore second pair of parentheses if any

Tags: regex, java-8

Im trying to split String using Regex. Example of the string is

`"3.5.1 (iOS 123; iPhone; Apple iPhone;) abcdef".`

So i was using this expression `"\\(|\\)"` and it was giving me three strings `"3.5.1 "`,  `"iOS 12; iPhone; Apple iPhone;"` and `" abcdef".`

But know ive discovered that sometimes string can look like this: `"3.5.1 (iOS 12; iPhone (details); Apple iPhone;) abcdef".`

So the goal is the same, to have three Strings either first option or `"3.5.1 "`, `"iOS 12; iPhone (detail); Apple iPhone;"` and `" abcdef"`.

Phones and os versions can be different form example. Is it possible to reach it using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `(...)` are balanaced, unescaped as shown in question, you can use this regex for matching:

```sh
^([^()]*?)\h*\((.*)\)\h*(.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RbmU00/8)

**RegEx Demo**

- `^`: Start of matcg
- `([^()]*?)`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `(` and `)`. Capture this text in group #1
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\(`: Match first `(`
- `(.*)`: Match 0 or or more characters (greedy). Capture this text in group #2
- `\)`: Match outermost `)`
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*)`: Match 0 or or more characters (greedy). Capture this text in group #3

Comment: Mate, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it won't work in my case. Strings in a question are just examples, actual string can contain any character including spaces. But the pattern I'm looking for is still same, exclude first and last parentheses and leave everything else.

Comment: Think i need to apologise for making unclear question. What im trying to do is to split String using Regex. Example of the string is "(iOS 123; iPhone; Apple iPhone;) abcdef".

Comment: No, this does not remove brackets at all

Comment: [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RbmU00/6) Desired text is in capture group #1 and #2

Comment: It worked mate, thank you! 

One last question, is there any chance to split String by outermost parentheses if it also has double in front, for example "3.50.1 (iOS 12; iPhone (details); Apple iPhone;) abcdef" or "3.50.1 (iOS 12; iPhone; Apple iPhone;) abcdef"?

Comment: I have already updated my answer to address these cases. Check regex and new demo and let me know.